# Alterar hora no sql server 2014

Tags: amazon-aws, sql-server-2014, timezone

Bom dia, como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo, fiz um select para pegar a data corrente e a mesma está em +3.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso alterar esta data/hora?

Comment: Muda a configuração do servidor pra pt-Br.

Comment: Minha pergunta é exatamente como e onde faço isso.

Comment: Painel de Controle -> Região e Idioma -> Alterar Local. Troca o Formato e o Local

Comment: Esta máquina está na amazon e não tenho acesso.

Comment: Funcionou @Douglas?

Comment: @Marconi é uma alternativa, provavelmente vamos usar esta mesmo.

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O SQL Server utiliza por padrão as configurações regionais que estão determinadas no seu Windows.

Você pode alterar somente a configuração do seu servidor:

*Painel de Controle -> Região e Idioma -> Alterar Local -> Troque o Formato e o Local*

Mais como você não tem acesso você pode criar uma Query que use a Função [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186819.aspx) subtraindo as 3 horas, dessa forma:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, -3, GETDATE())
```

*Resultado:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]